# Sending a request to the IRS ACA A2A BulkRequestTransmitter web service

Tags: xml, web-services, mtom, irs

I am trying to send a request to the IRS's BulkRequestTransmitter service. I am constructing the message manually using C# (not WCF, I'm just creating all of the XML). The XML I've constructed is valid, and I can sign it with an X509 certificate (so I am past the point of the WS-Security error that many people struggle with for this service).  I am also able to apply gzip compression to the outgoing request, and as far as I can tell, I am attaching the BulkExchangeFile properly. While working on this, I have occasionally seen errors telling me to ensure that the message is MTOM-encoded, but I have applied the appropriate headers and separators as far as I can tell, and the error message I currently receive is:

```
The message was not formatted properly and/or cannot be interpreted. Please review the XML standards outlined in Section 3 of the AIR Submission Composition and Reference Guide located at https://www.irs.gov/for-Tax-Pros/Software-Developers/Information-Returns/Affordable-Care-Act-Information-Return-AIR-Program, correct any issues, and try again.
```

A redacted version of my complete (uncompressed) request is below. Can anyone identify what is lacking here? Or if you have an example of a working request, would you please provide it?

```
POST https://la.www4.irs.gov/airp/aca/a2a/1095BC_Transmission_AATS2016 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<rootpart@place>"; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="------separation"
SOAPAction: "BulkRequestTransmitter"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Host: la.www4.irs.gov
Content-Length: 26656
Connection: Keep-Alive

------separation
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Disposition: form-data

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:urn1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:urn2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader" xmlns:urn3="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acasecurityheader" xmlns:urn4="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irsacabulkrequesttransmitter" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xd="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="X509-2536B72CF39EF8CCA91454680407206414">REDACTED</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><Signature Id="SIG-2536B72CF39EF8CCA91454680407206417" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><Reference URI="#TS-2536B72CF39EF8CCA91454680407204413"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse wsa oas1 soapenv urn urn1 urn2 urn3 urn4 xd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>o/EHDkngH0Cpjsznht+9hob6EJM=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#id-B123454679813489712349871234987123"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsa oas1 soapenv urn urn1 urn3 urn4 xd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>S+fJ7JQqtOBHu4ROJomDPCFBEzg=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#id-A123454679813489712349871234987123"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsa oas1 soapenv urn1 urn2 urn3 urn4 xd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>p2UkJzH2M6t0Sv5SZtBeXd2NmdE=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>REDACTED</SignatureValue><KeyInfo Id="KI-2536B72CF39EF8CCA91454680407206415"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="id-F123454679813489712349871234987123" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-2536B72CF39EF8CCA91454680407206414" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" /></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></KeyInfo></Signature><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-2536B72CF39EF8CCA91454680407204413"><wsu:Created>2016-02-15T20:49:03Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2016-02-15T20:49:04Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security>

     <urn:ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl wsu:Id="id-A123454679813489712349871234987123" xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common">
        <PaymentYr>2016</PaymentYr>
        <PriorYearDataInd>0</PriorYearDataInd>
        <irs:EIN>123456780</irs:EIN>
        <TransmissionTypeCd>O</TransmissionTypeCd>
        <TestFileCd>T</TestFileCd>
        <TransmitterNameGrp>
           <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Company</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
        </TransmitterNameGrp>
        <CompanyInformationGrp>
           <CompanyNm>Company</CompanyNm>
           <MailingAddressGrp>
              <USAddressGrp>
                 <AddressLine1Txt>100 Street Road</AddressLine1Txt>
                 <irs:CityNm>Pittsburgh</irs:CityNm>
                 <USStateCd>PA</USStateCd>
                 <irs:USZIPCd>15147</irs:USZIPCd>
              </USAddressGrp>
           </MailingAddressGrp>
           <ContactNameGrp>
              <PersonFirstNm>FirstName</PersonFirstNm>
              <PersonLastNm>LastName</PersonLastNm>
           </ContactNameGrp>
           <ContactPhoneNum>1234561333</ContactPhoneNum>
        </CompanyInformationGrp>
        <VendorInformationGrp>
           <VendorCd>I</VendorCd>
           <ContactNameGrp>
              <PersonFirstNm>FirstName</PersonFirstNm>
              <PersonLastNm>LastName</PersonLastNm>
           </ContactNameGrp>
           <ContactPhoneNum>1234561355</ContactPhoneNum>
        </VendorInformationGrp>
        <TotalPayeeRecordCnt>3</TotalPayeeRecordCnt>
        <TotalPayerRecordCnt>1</TotalPayerRecordCnt>
        <SoftwareId>REDACTED</SoftwareId>
        <FormTypeCd>1094/1095C</FormTypeCd>
        <irs:BinaryFormatCd>application/xml</irs:BinaryFormatCd>
        <irs:ChecksumAugmentationNum>88E29379045C75F748C50A42D41BE2B9</irs:ChecksumAugmentationNum>
        <irs:AttachmentByteSizeNum>13469</irs:AttachmentByteSizeNum>
        <DocumentSystemFileNm>1094C_Request_REDACTED_20160215T204902973Z.xml</DocumentSystemFileNm>
     </urn:ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl>


     <urn2:ACABusinessHeader wsu:Id="id-B123454679813489712349871234987123">
        <urn:UniqueTransmissionId>c8c22f37-aa2c-41a0-a262-da2fe16ea898:SYS12:REDACTED::T</urn:UniqueTransmissionId>
        <urn1:Timestamp>2016-02-15T20:49:03Z</urn1:Timestamp>
     </urn2:ACABusinessHeader>

  <wsa:Action>BulkRequestTransmitter</wsa:Action></soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <urn4:ACABulkRequestTransmitter version="1.0">
        <urn1:BulkExchangeFile>1094C_Request_REDACTED_20160215T204902973Z.xml</urn1:BulkExchangeFile>
     </urn4:ACABulkRequestTransmitter>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
------separation
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: form-data

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Ctransmitterupstreammessage IRS-Form1094-1095CTransmitterUpstreamMessage.xsd" xmlns:n1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Ctransmitterupstreammessage">
 <Form1094CUpstreamDetail recordType="" lineNum="0">
   <SubmissionId>1</SubmissionId>
   <TestScenarioId>3-0</TestScenarioId>
   <irs:TaxYr>2015</irs:TaxYr>
   <CorrectedInd>0</CorrectedInd>
   <EmployerInformationGrp>
     <BusinessName>
       <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Amazon Information</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
     </BusinessName>
     <BusinessNameControlTxt>AMAZ</BusinessNameControlTxt>
     <irs:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
     <irs:EmployerEIN>005234504</irs:EmployerEIN>
     <MailingAddressGrp>
       <USAddressGrp>
         <AddressLine1Txt>6689 Willow Court</AddressLine1Txt>
         <irs:CityNm>Beverly Hills</irs:CityNm>
         <USStateCd>CA</USStateCd>
         <irs:USZIPCd>90211</irs:USZIPCd>
       </USAddressGrp>
     </MailingAddressGrp>
     <ContactNameGrp>
       <PersonFirstNm>Rose</PersonFirstNm>
       <PersonMiddleNm>S</PersonMiddleNm>
       <PersonLastNm>Lincoln</PersonLastNm>
     </ContactNameGrp>
     <ContactPhoneNum>5559876543</ContactPhoneNum>
   </EmployerInformationGrp>
   <Form1095CAttachedCnt>3</Form1095CAttachedCnt>
   <AuthoritativeTransmittalInd>1</AuthoritativeTransmittalInd>
   <TotalForm1095CALEMemberCnt>455</TotalForm1095CALEMemberCnt>
   <AggregatedGroupMemberCd>1</AggregatedGroupMemberCd>
   <Section4980HReliefInd>1</Section4980HReliefInd>
   <ALEMemberInformationGrp>
     <YearlyALEMemberDetail>
       <AggregatedGroupInd>1</AggregatedGroupInd>
       <ALESect4980HTrnstReliefCd>B</ALESect4980HTrnstReliefCd>
     </YearlyALEMemberDetail>
     <JanALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
       <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>2</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
       <ALEMemberFTECnt>312</ALEMemberFTECnt>
       <TotalEmployeeCnt>351</TotalEmployeeCnt>
     </JanALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
     <FebALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
       <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>2</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
       <ALEMemberFTECnt>312</ALEMemberFTECnt>
       <TotalEmployeeCnt>352</TotalEmployeeCnt>
     </FebALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
     <MarALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
       <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>2</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
       <ALEMemberFTECnt>315</ALEMemberFTECnt>
       <TotalEmployeeCnt>358</TotalEmployeeCnt>
     </MarALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
     <AprALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
       <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>2</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
       <ALEMemberFTECnt>320</ALEMemberFTECnt>
       <TotalEmployeeCnt>365</TotalEmployeeCnt>
     </AprALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
     <MayALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
       <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>2</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
       <ALEMemberFTECnt>322</ALEMemberFTECnt>
       <TotalEmployeeCnt>369</TotalEmployeeCnt>
     </MayALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
     <JunALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
       <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
       <ALEMemberFTECnt>325</ALEMemberFTECnt>
       <TotalEmployeeCnt>376</TotalEmployeeCnt>
     </JunALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
     <JulALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
       <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
       <ALEMemberFTECnt>329</ALEMemberFTECnt>
       <TotalEmployeeCnt>372</TotalEmployeeCnt>
     </JulALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
     <AugALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
       <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
       <ALEMemberFTECnt>333</ALEMemberFTECnt>
       <TotalEmployeeCnt>369</TotalEmployeeCnt>
     </AugALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
     <SeptALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
       <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
       <ALEMemberFTECnt>341</ALEMemberFTECnt>
       <TotalEmployeeCnt>366</TotalEmployeeCnt>
     </SeptALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
     <OctALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
       <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
       <ALEMemberFTECnt>344</ALEMemberFTECnt>
       <TotalEmployeeCnt>363</TotalEmployeeCnt>
     </OctALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
     <NovALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
       <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
       <ALEMemberFTECnt>361</ALEMemberFTECnt>
       <TotalEmployeeCnt>377</TotalEmployeeCnt>
     </NovALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
     <DecALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
       <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
       <ALEMemberFTECnt>372</ALEMemberFTECnt>
       <TotalEmployeeCnt>385</TotalEmployeeCnt>
     </DecALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
   </ALEMemberInformationGrp>
   <OtherALEMembersGrp>
     <BusinessName>
       <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Danube Information Inc</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
     </BusinessName>
     <BusinessNameControlTxt>DANU</BusinessNameControlTxt>
     <irs:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
     <irs:EIN>005234507</irs:EIN>
   </OtherALEMembersGrp>
   <OtherALEMembersGrp>
     <BusinessName>
       <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Euphrates Limited</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
     </BusinessName>
     <BusinessNameControlTxt>EUPH</BusinessNameControlTxt>
     <irs:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
     <irs:EIN>005234508</irs:EIN>
   </OtherALEMembersGrp>
   <OtherALEMembersGrp>
     <BusinessName>
       <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Mackenzie Inc</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
     </BusinessName>
     <BusinessNameControlTxt>MACK</BusinessNameControlTxt>
     <irs:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
     <irs:EIN>005234505</irs:EIN>
   </OtherALEMembersGrp>
   <OtherALEMembersGrp>
     <BusinessName>
       <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Rio Grande Co</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
     </BusinessName>
     <BusinessNameControlTxt>RIO </BusinessNameControlTxt>
     <irs:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
     <irs:EIN>005234506</irs:EIN>
   </OtherALEMembersGrp>
   <Form1095CUpstreamDetail recordType="" lineNum="0">
     <RecordId>1393</RecordId>
     <TestScenarioId>3-1</TestScenarioId>
     <CorrectedInd>0</CorrectedInd>
     <irs:TaxYr>2015</irs:TaxYr>
     <EmployeeInfoGrp>
       <OtherCompletePersonName>
         <PersonFirstNm>Teresa</PersonFirstNm>
         <PersonMiddleNm>L</PersonMiddleNm>
         <PersonLastNm>Grays</PersonLastNm>
       </OtherCompletePersonName>
       <PersonNameControlTxt>GRAY</PersonNameControlTxt>
       <irs:SSN>400001016</irs:SSN>
       <MailingAddressGrp>
         <USAddressGrp>
           <AddressLine1Txt>342 Ash Avenue</AddressLine1Txt>
           <irs:CityNm>Seattle</irs:CityNm>
           <USStateCd>WA</USStateCd>
           <irs:USZIPCd>98104</irs:USZIPCd>
         </USAddressGrp>
       </MailingAddressGrp>
     </EmployeeInfoGrp>
     <ALEContactPhoneNum>5559876550</ALEContactPhoneNum>
     <StartMonthNumberCd>06</StartMonthNumberCd>
     <EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
       <MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp>
         <JanOfferCd>1H</JanOfferCd>
         <FebOfferCd>1H</FebOfferCd>
         <MarOfferCd>1H</MarOfferCd>
         <AprOfferCd>1H</AprOfferCd>
         <MayOfferCd>1H</MayOfferCd>
         <JunOfferCd>1E</JunOfferCd>
         <JulOfferCd>1E</JulOfferCd>
         <AugOfferCd>1E</AugOfferCd>
         <SepOfferCd>1E</SepOfferCd>
         <OctOfferCd>1E</OctOfferCd>
         <NovOfferCd>1E</NovOfferCd>
         <DecOfferCd>1E</DecOfferCd>
       </MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp>
       <MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
         <JuneAmt>139.00</JuneAmt>
         <JulyAmt>139.00</JulyAmt>
         <AugustAmt>139.00</AugustAmt>
         <SeptemberAmt>139.00</SeptemberAmt>
         <OctoberAmt>139.00</OctoberAmt>
         <NovemberAmt>139.00</NovemberAmt>
         <DecemberAmt>139.00</DecemberAmt>
       </MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
       <MonthlySafeHarborGrp>
         <JunSafeHarborCd>2C</JunSafeHarborCd>
         <JulSafeHarborCd>2C</JulSafeHarborCd>
         <AugSafeHarborCd>2C</AugSafeHarborCd>
         <SepSafeHarborCd>2C</SepSafeHarborCd>
         <OctSafeHarborCd>2C</OctSafeHarborCd>
         <NovSafeHarborCd>2C</NovSafeHarborCd>
         <DecSafeHarborCd>2C</DecSafeHarborCd>
       </MonthlySafeHarborGrp>
     </EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
   </Form1095CUpstreamDetail>
   <Form1095CUpstreamDetail recordType="" lineNum="0">
     <RecordId>1394</RecordId>
     <TestScenarioId>3-2</TestScenarioId>
     <CorrectedInd>0</CorrectedInd>
     <irs:TaxYr>2015</irs:TaxYr>
     <EmployeeInfoGrp>
       <OtherCompletePersonName>
         <PersonFirstNm>Wanda</PersonFirstNm>
         <PersonMiddleNm>S</PersonMiddleNm>
         <PersonLastNm>Antero</PersonLastNm>
       </OtherCompletePersonName>
       <PersonNameControlTxt>ANTE</PersonNameControlTxt>
       <irs:SSN>400001018</irs:SSN>
       <MailingAddressGrp>
         <USAddressGrp>
           <AddressLine1Txt>46789 Aspen Avenue</AddressLine1Txt>
           <irs:CityNm>Wasco</irs:CityNm>
           <USStateCd>OR</USStateCd>
           <irs:USZIPCd>97065</irs:USZIPCd>
         </USAddressGrp>
       </MailingAddressGrp>
     </EmployeeInfoGrp>
     <ALEContactPhoneNum>5559876550</ALEContactPhoneNum>
     <StartMonthNumberCd>06</StartMonthNumberCd>
     <EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
       <MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp>
         <JanOfferCd>1H</JanOfferCd>
         <FebOfferCd>1H</FebOfferCd>
         <MarOfferCd>1H</MarOfferCd>
         <AprOfferCd>1H</AprOfferCd>
         <MayOfferCd>1H</MayOfferCd>
         <JunOfferCd>1E</JunOfferCd>
         <JulOfferCd>1E</JulOfferCd>
         <AugOfferCd>1E</AugOfferCd>
         <SepOfferCd>1E</SepOfferCd>
         <OctOfferCd>1E</OctOfferCd>
         <NovOfferCd>1E</NovOfferCd>
         <DecOfferCd>1E</DecOfferCd>
       </MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp>
       <MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
         <JuneAmt>148.00</JuneAmt>
         <JulyAmt>148.00</JulyAmt>
         <AugustAmt>148.00</AugustAmt>
         <SeptemberAmt>148.00</SeptemberAmt>
         <OctoberAmt>148.00</OctoberAmt>
         <NovemberAmt>148.00</NovemberAmt>
         <DecemberAmt>148.00</DecemberAmt>
       </MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
       <MonthlySafeHarborGrp>
         <JunSafeHarborCd>2C</JunSafeHarborCd>
         <JulSafeHarborCd>2C</JulSafeHarborCd>
         <AugSafeHarborCd>2C</AugSafeHarborCd>
         <SepSafeHarborCd>2C</SepSafeHarborCd>
         <OctSafeHarborCd>2C</OctSafeHarborCd>
         <NovSafeHarborCd>2C</NovSafeHarborCd>
         <DecSafeHarborCd>2C</DecSafeHarborCd>
       </MonthlySafeHarborGrp>
     </EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
   </Form1095CUpstreamDetail>
   <Form1095CUpstreamDetail recordType="" lineNum="0">
     <RecordId>1395</RecordId>
     <TestScenarioId>3-3</TestScenarioId>
     <CorrectedInd>0</CorrectedInd>
     <irs:TaxYr>2015</irs:TaxYr>
     <EmployeeInfoGrp>
       <OtherCompletePersonName>
         <PersonFirstNm>Arthur</PersonFirstNm>
         <PersonMiddleNm>T</PersonMiddleNm>
         <PersonLastNm>Torreys</PersonLastNm>
       </OtherCompletePersonName>
       <PersonNameControlTxt>TORR</PersonNameControlTxt>
       <irs:SSN>400001022</irs:SSN>
       <MailingAddressGrp>
         <USAddressGrp>
           <AddressLine1Txt>4375 Alder Lane</AddressLine1Txt>
           <irs:CityNm>Kent</irs:CityNm>
           <USStateCd>WA</USStateCd>
           <irs:USZIPCd>98089</irs:USZIPCd>
         </USAddressGrp>
       </MailingAddressGrp>
     </EmployeeInfoGrp>
     <ALEContactPhoneNum>5559876550</ALEContactPhoneNum>
     <StartMonthNumberCd>06</StartMonthNumberCd>
     <EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
       <MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp>
         <JanOfferCd>1H</JanOfferCd>
         <FebOfferCd>1H</FebOfferCd>
         <MarOfferCd>1H</MarOfferCd>
         <AprOfferCd>1H</AprOfferCd>
         <MayOfferCd>1H</MayOfferCd>
         <JunOfferCd>1C</JunOfferCd>
         <JulOfferCd>1C</JulOfferCd>
         <AugOfferCd>1C</AugOfferCd>
         <SepOfferCd>1C</SepOfferCd>
         <OctOfferCd>1C</OctOfferCd>
         <NovOfferCd>1C</NovOfferCd>
         <DecOfferCd>1C</DecOfferCd>
       </MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp>
       <MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
         <JuneAmt>145.00</JuneAmt>
         <JulyAmt>145.00</JulyAmt>
         <AugustAmt>145.00</AugustAmt>
         <SeptemberAmt>145.00</SeptemberAmt>
         <OctoberAmt>145.00</OctoberAmt>
         <NovemberAmt>145.00</NovemberAmt>
         <DecemberAmt>145.00</DecemberAmt>
       </MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
       <MonthlySafeHarborGrp>
         <JunSafeHarborCd>2C</JunSafeHarborCd>
         <JulSafeHarborCd>2C</JulSafeHarborCd>
         <AugSafeHarborCd>2C</AugSafeHarborCd>
         <SepSafeHarborCd>2C</SepSafeHarborCd>
         <OctSafeHarborCd>2C</OctSafeHarborCd>
         <NovSafeHarborCd>2C</NovSafeHarborCd>
         <DecSafeHarborCd>2C</DecSafeHarborCd>
       </MonthlySafeHarborGrp>
     </EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
   </Form1095CUpstreamDetail>
 </Form1094CUpstreamDetail>
</n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream>
------separation--
```

Comment: I'm just about at the same spot, and I think the quirk is in section: 5.3.2.2
ACA SOAP Header Elements to be Digitally Encrypted. There it says these need to be ENCRYPTED, not just signed. 

ACABusinessHeader, ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl, Timestamp

Comment: Honestly, this is one of the most frustrating experiences of my career. I wish the IRS would publish a sample fully prepared SOAP uncompressed message, with HTTP headers and everything. Feels like shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your BulkExchangeFile element isn't correct. Should look more like:

```
<BulkExchangeFile xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common">
    <xop:Include href="cid:UZE_26123_" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" />
</BulkExchangeFile>
```

And then the MIME header for your attachment also needs a new header to match the href in the Include element:

```
Content-Id: <UZE_26123_>
```

Use whatever identifiers you want, of course.

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments

ctrl+f for "content-id" to see example.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up taking a similar approach after struggling with many different approaches (WCF, Java, etc.). Currently my requests will be accepted and return a ReceiptId from the IRS, but for some reason the file is not visible on IRS after upload (its doesn't show up in UI or thru A2A channel SOAP request to get status by ReceiptId).

Here are the header and separators:

```
POST https://la.www4.irs.gov/airp/aca/a2a/1095BC_Transmission_AATS2016 HTTP/1.1
Accept: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<http://tempuri.org/0>"; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="----=_Part_11_738624780.1455642659312"
SOAPAction: BulkRequestTransmitter
MIME-Version: 1.0
User-Agent: .NET Framework Example Client
Host: la.www4.irs.gov
Content-Length: 32338
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

------=_Part_11_738624780.1455642659312
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>

...soap envelope....

------=_Part_11_738624780.1455642659312
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/2/635900495259864817>
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=1094B_Request_REDACTED_20160203T160136015Z.xml

....attachment file contents....

------=_Part_11_738624780.1455642659312--
```

Here's the reference in soap body to bulk exchange file:

```
<urn1:BulkExchangeFile>
    <inc:Include href="cid:http://tempuri.org/2/635900495259864817" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" />
</urn1:BulkExchangeFile>
```

Answer (score 2):

I keep going back and forth on using the Service References (proxy client) and creating the `SOAP XML` manually like has been done by the OP.

I am using `C#` and `Visual Studio 2013`.

My Service Reference solution runs into the error:

> "The WS Security Header in the message is invalid. Please review the transmission instructions outlined in Section 5 of the AIR Submission Composition and Reference Guide located at https://www.irs.gov/for-Tax-Pros/Software-Developers/Information-Returns/Affordable-Care-Act-Information-Return-AIR-Program, correct any issues, and try again."

I have posted a question regarding the Service Reference error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466924/irs-a2a-ws-security-header-is-invalid).

My manual solution, however, runs into the following error message.  Which I believe to be the same error the OP was running into.

> The message was not formatted properly and/or cannot be interpreted. Please review the XML standards outlined in Section 3 of the AIR Submission Composition and Reference Guide located at https://www.irs.gov/for-Tax-Pros/Software-Developers/Information-Returns/Affordable-Care-Act-Information-Return-AIR-Program, correct any issues, and try again.

To the best of my knowledge, I have made my XML a hybrid of the OP and @jabtri's requests.

Does anyone see any glaring mistakes?

*Note: I see now that one of my `<DigestValue>` elements now displays `System.Byte[]`, while the others are empty.  The application was not retrieving the correct SHA1 byte[] when I was setting the value of this field.  I started playing with it as I was posting this.  At the moment, I'm not sure why it is happening.*

```
POST https://la.www4.irs.gov/airp/aca/a2a/1095BC_Transmission_AATS2016 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
SOAPAction: BulkRequestTransmitterService
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related, type="application/xop+xml"; start="<http://tempuri.org/0>"; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="------=a3aa1db3d15149fa8d66f9707f310a17"
Host: la.www4.irs.gov
Content-Length: 21976
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive


------=a3aa1db3d15149fa8d66f9707f310a17
Content-Type:application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit
Content-Id:<http://tempuri.org/0>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:urn1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:urn2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader" xmlns:urn3="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acasecurityheader" xmlns:urn4="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irsacabulkrequesttransmitter" xmlns:xd="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <oas1:Security>
      <oas1:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" oas:Id="X509-891a2e2a1d82414e9620d3e507d66ca7">REDACTED</oas1:BinarySecurityToken>
      <xd:Signature Id="SIG-E61ed6a9b57aa4cfeb40fbef6042da2e2">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments" />
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
          <Reference URI="#TS-Ea131e673c5d94d7c8d446238f9e19fd6" />
          <Transforms>
            <Transform Algorithm="http://wwww.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
              <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse wsa oas1 soapenv urn urn1 urn2 urn3 urn4 xd" />
            </Transform>
          </Transforms>
          <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
          <DigestValue>System.Byte[]</DigestValue>
          <Reference URI="#id-E20df6a19a68148eaac5d9f0d444a2c66" />
          <Transforms>
            <Transform Algorithm="http://wwww.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
              <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse wsa oas1 soapenv urn urn1 urn2 urn3 urn4 xd" />
            </Transform>
          </Transforms>
          <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
          <DigestValue />
          <Reference URI="#id-Ebde61cd55b424f87b66e6bf0ce504b71" />
          <Transforms>
            <Transform Algorithm="http://wwww.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
              <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse wsa oas1 soapenv urn urn1 urn2 urn3 urn4 xd" />
            </Transform>
          </Transforms>
          <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
          <DigestValue />
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>REDACTED</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo Id="KI-E9cb81a0e992b4a3d892af9a17fca2ca9">
          <wsse11:SecurityTokenReference oas:Id="id-Fe2ff8913a0944a4ea0c1e77ee366be2e" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1">
            <wsse11:Reference URI="#X509-891a2e2a1d82414e9620d3e507d66ca7" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" />
          </wsse11:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </xd:Signature>
      <oas:Timestamp oas:Id="TS-Ea131e673c5d94d7c8d446238f9e19fd6">
        <oas:Created>2016-02-17T12:04:01.766Z</oas:Created>
        <oas:Expires>2016-02-17T12:04:01.766Z</oas:Expires>
      </oas:Timestamp>
    </oas1:Security>
    <urn:ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl oas:Id="id-E20df6a19a68148eaac5d9f0d444a2c66">
      <urn:PaymentYr>2015</urn:PaymentYr>
      <urn:PriorYearDataInd>0</urn:PriorYearDataInd>
      <urn1:EIN>123456780</urn1:EIN>
      <urn:TransmissionTypeCd>O</urn:TransmissionTypeCd>
      <urn:TestFileCd>T</urn:TestFileCd>
      <urn:OriginalReceiptId></urn:OriginalReceiptId>
      <urn:TransmitterNameGrp>
        <urn:BusinessNameLine1Txt>Company</urn:BusinessNameLine1Txt>
      </urn:TransmitterNameGrp>
      <urn:CompanyInformationGrp>
        <urn:CompanyNm>Company</urn:CompanyNm>
        <urn:MailingAddressGrp>
          <urn:AddressLine1Txt>Company Address Line 1</urn:AddressLine1Txt>
          <urn1:CityNm>Company City</urn1:CityNm>
          <urn:USStateCd>Company State</urn:USStateCd>
          <urn:USZIPCd>12345</urn:USZIPCd>
        </urn:MailingAddressGrp>
        <urn:ContactNameGrp>
          <urn:PersonFirstNm>First Name</urn:PersonFirstNm>
          <urn:PersonLastNm>Last Name</urn:PersonLastNm>
        </urn:ContactNameGrp>
        <urn:ContactPhoneNum>5559876543</urn:ContactPhoneNum>
      </urn:CompanyInformationGrp>
      <urn:VendorInformationGrp>
        <urn:VendorCd>I</urn:VendorCd>
        <urn:ContactNameGrp>
          <urn:PersonFirstNm>First Name</urn:PersonFirstNm>
          <urn:PersonLastNm>Last Name</urn:PersonLastNm>
        </urn:ContactNameGrp>
        <urn:ContactPhoneNum>1234561335</urn:ContactPhoneNum>
      </urn:VendorInformationGrp>
      <urn:TotalPayeeRecordCnt>3</urn:TotalPayeeRecordCnt>
      <urn:TotalPayerRecordCnt>1</urn:TotalPayerRecordCnt>
      <urn:SoftwareId>REDACTED</urn:SoftwareId>
      <urn:FormTypeCd>1094/1095C</urn:FormTypeCd>
      <urn1:BinaryFormatCd>application/xml</urn1:BinaryFormatCd>
      <urn1:ChecksumAugmentationNum>4f8367383527f00d353a7cc1f0c472ef</urn1:ChecksumAugmentationNum>
      <urn1:AttachmentByteSizeNum>14071</urn1:AttachmentByteSizeNum>
      <urn:DocumentSystemFileNm>Form1094C_Request_REDACTED_20160217T2003478641Z.xml</urn:DocumentSystemFileNm>
    </urn:ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl>
    <urn2:ACABusinessHeader oas:Id="id-Ebde61cd55b424f87b66e6bf0ce504b71">
      <urn:UniqueTransmissionId>9145639f-6b2e-47ef-bad8-ec771f1bb352:SYS12:REDACTED::T</urn:UniqueTransmissionId>
      <urn:Timestamp>2016-02-17T20:04:01.6181067Z</urn:Timestamp>
    </urn2:ACABusinessHeader>
    <wsa:Action>BulkRequestTransmitterService</wsa:Action>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <urn4:ACABulkRequestTransmitter version="1.0">
      <urn1:BulkExchangeFile>
        <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:Form1094C_Request_REDACTED_20160217T2003478641Z.xml" />
      </urn1:BulkExchangeFile>
    </urn4:ACABulkRequestTransmitter>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

------=a3aa1db3d15149fa8d66f9707f310a17
Content-Id:<http://tempuri.org/2/635906947734098872>
Content-Type:application/xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding:7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Form1094C_Request_REDACTED_20160217T2003478641Z.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Btransmitterupstreammessage IRS-Form1094-1095BTransmitterUpstreamMessage.xsd" xmlns:n1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Ctransmitterupstreammessage">
  <Form1094CUpstreamDetail recordType="String" lineNum="0">
    <SubmissionId>1</SubmissionId>
    <TestScenarioId>3-0</TestScenarioId>
    <irs:TaxYr>2015</irs:TaxYr>
    <CorrectedInd>0</CorrectedInd>
    <EmployerInformationGrp>
      <BusinessName>
        <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Selitestthree</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
      </BusinessName>
      <irs:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
      <irs:EmployerEIN>000000301</irs:EmployerEIN>
      <MailingAddressGrp>
        <USAddressGrp>
          <AddressLine1Txt>6689 Willow Court</AddressLine1Txt>
          <irs:CityNm>Beverly Hills</irs:CityNm>
          <USStateCd>CA</USStateCd>
          <irs:USZIPCd>90211</irs:USZIPCd>
        </USAddressGrp>
      </MailingAddressGrp>
      <ContactNameGrp>
        <PersonFirstNm>Rose</PersonFirstNm>
        <PersonLastNm>Lincoln</PersonLastNm>
      </ContactNameGrp>
      <ContactPhoneNum>5559876543</ContactPhoneNum>
    </EmployerInformationGrp>
    <Form1095CAttachedCnt>3</Form1095CAttachedCnt>
    <AuthoritativeTransmittalInd>1</AuthoritativeTransmittalInd>
    <TotalForm1095CALEMemberCnt>3</TotalForm1095CALEMemberCnt>
    <AggregatedGroupMemberCd>1</AggregatedGroupMemberCd>
    <QualifyingOfferMethodInd>0</QualifyingOfferMethodInd>
    <QlfyOfferMethodTrnstReliefInd>0</QlfyOfferMethodTrnstReliefInd>
    <Section4980HReliefInd>1</Section4980HReliefInd>
    <NinetyEightPctOfferMethodInd>0</NinetyEightPctOfferMethodInd>
    <irs:SignatureDt>2016-02-16</irs:SignatureDt>
    <ALEMemberInformationGrp>
      <YearlyALEMemberDetail>
        <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>0</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
        <AggregatedGroupInd>1</AggregatedGroupInd>
        <ALESect4980HTrnstReliefCd>B</ALESect4980HTrnstReliefCd>
      </YearlyALEMemberDetail>
      <JanALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
        <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>2</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
        <ALEMemberFTECnt>312</ALEMemberFTECnt>
        <TotalEmployeeCnt>351</TotalEmployeeCnt>
        <AggregatedGroupInd>0</AggregatedGroupInd>
      </JanALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
      <FebALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
        <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>2</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
        <ALEMemberFTECnt>312</ALEMemberFTECnt>
        <TotalEmployeeCnt>352</TotalEmployeeCnt>
        <AggregatedGroupInd>0</AggregatedGroupInd>
      </FebALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
      <MarALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
        <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>2</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
        <ALEMemberFTECnt>315</ALEMemberFTECnt>
        <TotalEmployeeCnt>358</TotalEmployeeCnt>
        <AggregatedGroupInd>0</AggregatedGroupInd>
      </MarALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
      <AprALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
        <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>2</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
        <ALEMemberFTECnt>320</ALEMemberFTECnt>
        <TotalEmployeeCnt>365</TotalEmployeeCnt>
        <AggregatedGroupInd>0</AggregatedGroupInd>
      </AprALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
      <MayALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
        <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>2</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
        <ALEMemberFTECnt>322</ALEMemberFTECnt>
        <TotalEmployeeCnt>369</TotalEmployeeCnt>
        <AggregatedGroupInd>0</AggregatedGroupInd>
      </MayALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
      <JunALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
        <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
        <ALEMemberFTECnt>325</ALEMemberFTECnt>
        <TotalEmployeeCnt>376</TotalEmployeeCnt>
        <AggregatedGroupInd>0</AggregatedGroupInd>
      </JunALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
      <JulALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
        <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
        <ALEMemberFTECnt>329</ALEMemberFTECnt>
        <TotalEmployeeCnt>372</TotalEmployeeCnt>
        <AggregatedGroupInd>0</AggregatedGroupInd>
      </JulALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
      <AugALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
        <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
        <ALEMemberFTECnt>333</ALEMemberFTECnt>
        <TotalEmployeeCnt>369</TotalEmployeeCnt>
        <AggregatedGroupInd>0</AggregatedGroupInd>
      </AugALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
      <SeptALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
        <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
        <ALEMemberFTECnt>341</ALEMemberFTECnt>
        <TotalEmployeeCnt>366</TotalEmployeeCnt>
        <AggregatedGroupInd>0</AggregatedGroupInd>
      </SeptALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
      <OctALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
        <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
        <ALEMemberFTECnt>344</ALEMemberFTECnt>
        <TotalEmployeeCnt>363</TotalEmployeeCnt>
        <AggregatedGroupInd>0</AggregatedGroupInd>
      </OctALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
      <NovALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
        <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
        <ALEMemberFTECnt>361</ALEMemberFTECnt>
        <TotalEmployeeCnt>377</TotalEmployeeCnt>
        <AggregatedGroupInd>0</AggregatedGroupInd>
      </NovALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
      <DecALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
        <MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>1</MinEssentialCvrOffrCd>
        <ALEMemberFTECnt>372</ALEMemberFTECnt>
        <TotalEmployeeCnt>385</TotalEmployeeCnt>
        <AggregatedGroupInd>0</AggregatedGroupInd>
      </DecALEMonthlyInfoGrp>
    </ALEMemberInformationGrp>
    <OtherALEMembersGrp>
      <BusinessName>
        <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Selitestthree Subsidiary One</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
      </BusinessName>
      <irs:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
      <irs:EIN>000000302</irs:EIN>
    </OtherALEMembersGrp>
    <OtherALEMembersGrp>
      <BusinessName>
        <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Selitestthree Subsidiary Two</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
      </BusinessName>
      <irs:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
      <irs:EIN>000000303</irs:EIN>
    </OtherALEMembersGrp>
    <OtherALEMembersGrp>
      <BusinessName>
        <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Selitestthree Subsidiary Three</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
      </BusinessName>
      <irs:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
      <irs:EIN>000000304</irs:EIN>
    </OtherALEMembersGrp>
    <OtherALEMembersGrp>
      <BusinessName>
        <BusinessNameLine1Txt>Selitestthree Subsidiary Four</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
      </BusinessName>
      <irs:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
      <irs:EIN>000000305</irs:EIN>
    </OtherALEMembersGrp>
    <Form1095CUpstreamDetail recordType="String" lineNum="0">
      <RecordId>1</RecordId>
      <TestScenarioId>3-1</TestScenarioId>
      <CorrectedInd>0</CorrectedInd>
      <irs:TaxYr>2015</irs:TaxYr>
      <EmployeeInfoGrp>
        <OtherCompletePersonName>
          <PersonFirstNm>Teresa</PersonFirstNm>
          <PersonLastNm>Southern</PersonLastNm>
        </OtherCompletePersonName>
        <irs:TINRequestTypeCd>INDIVIDUAL_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
        <irs:SSN>000000350</irs:SSN>
        <MailingAddressGrp>
          <USAddressGrp>
            <AddressLine1Txt>342 Ash Avenue</AddressLine1Txt>
            <irs:CityNm>Seattle</irs:CityNm>
            <USStateCd>WA</USStateCd>
            <irs:USZIPCd>98104</irs:USZIPCd>
          </USAddressGrp>
        </MailingAddressGrp>
      </EmployeeInfoGrp>
      <ALEContactPhoneNum>5559876543</ALEContactPhoneNum>
      <StartMonthNumberCd>06</StartMonthNumberCd>
      <EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
        <MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp>
          <JanOfferCd>1H</JanOfferCd>
          <FebOfferCd>1H</FebOfferCd>
          <MarOfferCd>1H</MarOfferCd>
          <AprOfferCd>1H</AprOfferCd>
          <MayOfferCd>1H</MayOfferCd>
          <JunOfferCd>1E</JunOfferCd>
          <JulOfferCd>1E</JulOfferCd>
          <AugOfferCd>1E</AugOfferCd>
          <SepOfferCd>1E</SepOfferCd>
          <OctOfferCd>1E</OctOfferCd>
          <NovOfferCd>1E</NovOfferCd>
          <DecOfferCd>1E</DecOfferCd>
        </MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp>
        <MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
          <JuneAmt>139.00</JuneAmt>
          <JulyAmt>139.00</JulyAmt>
          <AugustAmt>139.00</AugustAmt>
          <SeptemberAmt>139.00</SeptemberAmt>
          <OctoberAmt>139.00</OctoberAmt>
          <NovemberAmt>139.00</NovemberAmt>
          <DecemberAmt>139.00</DecemberAmt>
        </MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
        <MonthlySafeHarborGrp>
          <JunSafeHarborCd>2C</JunSafeHarborCd>
          <JulSafeHarborCd>2C</JulSafeHarborCd>
          <AugSafeHarborCd>2C</AugSafeHarborCd>
          <SepSafeHarborCd>2C</SepSafeHarborCd>
          <OctSafeHarborCd>2C</OctSafeHarborCd>
          <NovSafeHarborCd>2C</NovSafeHarborCd>
          <DecSafeHarborCd>2C</DecSafeHarborCd>
        </MonthlySafeHarborGrp>
      </EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
      <CoveredIndividualInd>0</CoveredIndividualInd>
    </Form1095CUpstreamDetail>
    <Form1095CUpstreamDetail recordType="String" lineNum="0">
      <RecordId>2</RecordId>
      <TestScenarioId>3-2</TestScenarioId>
      <CorrectedInd>0</CorrectedInd>
      <irs:TaxYr>2015</irs:TaxYr>
      <EmployeeInfoGrp>
        <OtherCompletePersonName>
          <PersonFirstNm>Wanda</PersonFirstNm>
          <PersonLastNm>Souter</PersonLastNm>
        </OtherCompletePersonName>
        <irs:TINRequestTypeCd>INDIVIDUAL_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
        <irs:SSN>000000351</irs:SSN>
        <MailingAddressGrp>
          <USAddressGrp>
            <AddressLine1Txt>46789 Aspen Avenue</AddressLine1Txt>
            <irs:CityNm>Wasco</irs:CityNm>
            <USStateCd>OR</USStateCd>
            <irs:USZIPCd>97065</irs:USZIPCd>
          </USAddressGrp>
        </MailingAddressGrp>
      </EmployeeInfoGrp>
      <ALEContactPhoneNum>5559876543</ALEContactPhoneNum>
      <StartMonthNumberCd>06</StartMonthNumberCd>
      <EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
        <MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp>
          <JanOfferCd>1H</JanOfferCd>
          <FebOfferCd>1H</FebOfferCd>
          <MarOfferCd>1H</MarOfferCd>
          <AprOfferCd>1H</AprOfferCd>
          <MayOfferCd>1H</MayOfferCd>
          <JunOfferCd>1E</JunOfferCd>
          <JulOfferCd>1E</JulOfferCd>
          <AugOfferCd>1E</AugOfferCd>
          <SepOfferCd>1E</SepOfferCd>
          <OctOfferCd>1E</OctOfferCd>
          <NovOfferCd>1E</NovOfferCd>
          <DecOfferCd>1E</DecOfferCd>
        </MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp>
        <MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
          <JuneAmt>148.00</JuneAmt>
          <JulyAmt>148.00</JulyAmt>
          <AugustAmt>148.00</AugustAmt>
          <SeptemberAmt>148.00</SeptemberAmt>
          <OctoberAmt>148.00</OctoberAmt>
          <NovemberAmt>148.00</NovemberAmt>
          <DecemberAmt>148.00</DecemberAmt>
        </MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
        <MonthlySafeHarborGrp>
          <JunSafeHarborCd>2C</JunSafeHarborCd>
          <JulSafeHarborCd>2C</JulSafeHarborCd>
          <AugSafeHarborCd>2C</AugSafeHarborCd>
          <SepSafeHarborCd>2C</SepSafeHarborCd>
          <OctSafeHarborCd>2C</OctSafeHarborCd>
          <NovSafeHarborCd>2C</NovSafeHarborCd>
          <DecSafeHarborCd>2C</DecSafeHarborCd>
        </MonthlySafeHarborGrp>
      </EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
      <CoveredIndividualInd>0</CoveredIndividualInd>
    </Form1095CUpstreamDetail>
    <Form1095CUpstreamDetail recordType="String" lineNum="0">
      <RecordId>3</RecordId>
      <TestScenarioId>3-3</TestScenarioId>
      <CorrectedInd>0</CorrectedInd>
      <irs:TaxYr>2015</irs:TaxYr>
      <EmployeeInfoGrp>
        <OtherCompletePersonName>
          <PersonFirstNm>Arthur</PersonFirstNm>
          <PersonLastNm>Soutane</PersonLastNm>
        </OtherCompletePersonName>
        <irs:TINRequestTypeCd>INDIVIDUAL_TIN</irs:TINRequestTypeCd>
        <irs:SSN>000000355</irs:SSN>
        <MailingAddressGrp>
          <USAddressGrp>
            <AddressLine1Txt>4375 Alder Lane</AddressLine1Txt>
            <irs:CityNm>Kent</irs:CityNm>
            <USStateCd>WA</USStateCd>
            <irs:USZIPCd>98089</irs:USZIPCd>
          </USAddressGrp>
        </MailingAddressGrp>
      </EmployeeInfoGrp>
      <ALEContactPhoneNum>5559876543</ALEContactPhoneNum>
      <StartMonthNumberCd>06</StartMonthNumberCd>
      <EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
        <MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp>
          <JanOfferCd>1H</JanOfferCd>
          <FebOfferCd>1H</FebOfferCd>
          <MarOfferCd>1H</MarOfferCd>
          <AprOfferCd>1H</AprOfferCd>
          <MayOfferCd>1H</MayOfferCd>
          <JunOfferCd>1C</JunOfferCd>
          <JulOfferCd>1C</JulOfferCd>
          <AugOfferCd>1C</AugOfferCd>
          <SepOfferCd>1C</SepOfferCd>
          <OctOfferCd>1C</OctOfferCd>
          <NovOfferCd>1C</NovOfferCd>
          <DecOfferCd>1C</DecOfferCd>
        </MonthlyOfferCoverageGrp>
        <MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
          <JuneAmt>145.00</JuneAmt>
          <JulyAmt>145.00</JulyAmt>
          <AugustAmt>145.00</AugustAmt>
          <SeptemberAmt>145.00</SeptemberAmt>
          <OctoberAmt>145.00</OctoberAmt>
          <NovemberAmt>145.00</NovemberAmt>
          <DecemberAmt>145.00</DecemberAmt>
        </MonthlyShareOfLowestCostMonthlyPremGrp>
        <MonthlySafeHarborGrp>
          <JunSafeHarborCd>2C</JunSafeHarborCd>
          <JulSafeHarborCd>2C</JulSafeHarborCd>
          <AugSafeHarborCd>2C</AugSafeHarborCd>
          <SepSafeHarborCd>2C</SepSafeHarborCd>
          <OctSafeHarborCd>2C</OctSafeHarborCd>
          <NovSafeHarborCd>2C</NovSafeHarborCd>
          <DecSafeHarborCd>2C</DecSafeHarborCd>
        </MonthlySafeHarborGrp>
      </EmployeeOfferAndCoverageGrp>
      <CoveredIndividualInd>0</CoveredIndividualInd>
    </Form1095CUpstreamDetail>
  </Form1094CUpstreamDetail>
</n1:Form109495CTransmittalUpstream>
------=a3aa1db3d15149fa8d66f9707f310a17--
```

Comment: Hi  @Russ I'm too developing IRS related stuff.. Pls ping me so that we can code as a community and share the common problem faced, and its solutions

Comment: @MuthuGanapathyNathan Hello, I try and check the irs tag periodically.  Everything is currently working in my solution which was assisted in development through Q & A's within this community; I tried to update my questions with notes on whether my approach worked or did not work; however, I don't think I got through all of them.  If you have a specific question related to the irs tag, please post it, and I (along with other community members) will do our best to answer your questions.

Comment: How do you demo'ed the IRS to get transmitter permission. Any insights on that?

Comment: I do not understand your question as written.  Have you followed the IRS Transmission Guide, Composition Guide, and other documentation they have provided?  I believe these should assist in answering your question. 
 You may also contact them if you have been setup with the appropriate authority to do so.

Comment: Hi @Russ, we have many questions regrading the integration.. What I asked is have you shown any demo to IRS, to get transmitter permission? As we see, IRS are so slow in responding, for you too, is that the case... ? Also do you maintain Audit_0.txt in your side..

Comment: I did not have to demo a solution to the IRS in order to get permission to transmit; I did have to pass AATS testing and verification steps. I do not maintain an Audit_0.txt file, but I do have other means of auditing a variety of items. Yes, the IRS can be slow to respond, especially this time of year, due to the higher volume of calls and requests. Finally, in order to push data to their production environment, you must first pass AATS testing. This should assist in proving your solution works; however, you may run into other issues which AATS does not cover.