# IRS-A2A: WS Security Header is invalid

Tags: c#, web-services, soap-client, irs

I keep going back and forth on using the Service References (proxy client) and creating the `SOAP XML` manually.  I imported the `WSDL` files into my project as Service References.  I use the objects provided by these references to create populate my request.

My Code Base is C# using Visual Studio 2013.

My Service Reference solution runs into the error:

> "The WS Security Header in the message is invalid. Please review the transmission instructions outlined in Section 5 of the AIR Submission Composition and Reference Guide located at https://www.irs.gov/for-Tax-Pros/Software-Developers/Information-Returns/Affordable-Care-Act-Information-Return-AIR-Program, correct any issues, and try again."

1. How are other folks passing Security successfully through the Web Service to the IRS?
2. Any thoughts on how to resolve the issue I am facing by using the proxy client?
   the proxy client?

**Update**
I have abandoned the approach of using the `WSDL` files as Service References, and am manually creating the `SOAP` Request for transmittal.

Comment: I don't think anyone using .Net is and I am starting to believe it isn't our fault. I think their XML parser is fantasically broken. I've pored over my output for days, tweaking the most inconsequential of things with no progress at all. Fiddler outputs side by side with their documentation, character by character comparisons. And the only differences of substance are namespace declarations. But the ones I've constructed and their inheritance is valid, leading me to believe their junk is broken.

Comment: It's entirely possible, given how much "help" they have given us.  The last two questions I've asked have been met with responses of _"We'll get back to you in seven days."_  My manual SOAP creation, is using the proxy classes as a means to retrieve data from, since that coding was already done based on assuming their classes were correct and functional.  How are you solving this relative pain in the neck.  I would love some collaboration or at least someone to directly converse and bounce ideas off of.